# How can I make an endpoint accessible only for the user that has the id contained in that endpoint using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I have created an API using Spring Boot with the database (Postgres) that manages employees and departments. I'm using java 20, Spring Boot 3.0.1 and Spring security 6, And I created this endpoint "**/api/employees**" accessible only for the admin because it return all the employees in the database, and I have this endpoint **/api/employees/{id}** that return the specific employee with the given **id**.
By the way I didn't create any controller for employees or department because I used HATEOES which means that it creates for me the endpoints for the employees and the departments with writing any code.
Here's the Security configuration file:

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final RSAKeyProperties keys;

    public SecurityConfig(RSAKeyProperties keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll(); // This will allow anyone to access this endpoint in
            // order to Login or Signup
            auth.requestMatchers("/api/employees").hasRole("ADMIN");
            auth.requestMatchers("/api/employees/{id}");
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });
        httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getPrivateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtConverter;
    }

}
```

What I'm asking is how can I make this endpoint "**/api/employees/{id}**" accessible only for the employee that has the same **id** ?

I'm new to Spring Security so I couldn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, i would recommend binding the business logic to your id, let's say for example you have **employeeService** and it has findByEmail method in restClientController

a code example would be like this

```
 @GET("employee/{id}")
 public Response getClient(@AuthHeader("Token") String token ) {
       String email  = /** code to get the user's email or something **/
       try {
           Employee employee = employeeService.findByEmail(email);
           return Response
                        .ok(employee)
                        .build();
       } catch (Exception e) {
       /** exception logic **/
          return Response.status(Response.status.ERROR).build();
       }
```

}

your method business logic (this is the bare minimum) would be something like!

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).